# How to stretch the column on double click

Tags: visualforce, javascript, pageblocktable

[image]Primary when click the button it is showing like this for example : we can get the heardname"Author" as data initially show as "tatyana c" .

if we want to see the the full name .currently it is possible with dragging the column above. i want to double click to stretch the entire column .

when i double click at the author it has to show the full name "tatyana chirana".

Here is my code:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!quo}" var="q" rendered="{!(quo.size!= 0) && (quo.size < 999)}"  id="tblQuotes" styleclass="floatingHeaderTable" > 
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.From1__c}" styleClass="noWrap"  style="border:1px ridge #D7D8D9;" headerValue="Author" />
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_Number_New__c}" styleClass="noWrap"  style="border:1px ridge #D7D8D9;" headerValue="Nicomatic Quote Number"/>
                <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Name}" styleClass="noWrap"  style="border:1px ridge #D7D8D9" headerValue="SF Quote Number"/>
               <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Quote_Validity__c}" styleClass="noWrap"  style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Quote Validity"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.RFQ_Date__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="RFQ Date"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.createdDate__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Created Date"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Account_Code__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Account Code"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__r.Account_Name__c}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Account Name"/>
                 <apex:column value="{!q.Quote_Line_Item__r.Name}" styleClass="noWrap" style="border:1px solid #D7D8D9" headerValue="Nicomatic P/N"/>
```

Style for wrapping:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .noWrap { white-space: nowrap;}
</style>
```

For col Resizable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $("[id$=tblQuotes]").colResizable({
            liveDrag: true,
            draggingClass: "dragging"
          });    
</script>
```

I need that in such a way that double click header separator we use in excel . Double click on the author to show to entire full data in that cell .

Comment: ... think you should link to the jQuery plugin which presumably is http://quocity.com/colresizable/?

Comment: i am already using that one

Comment: Yes I noticed that from the presence of colResizable in your code. I was suggesting that your question would be clearer if you linked to it as any dblclick function proposed will have to fit in with it.